# Perl: How to search in directory, for file-type, sorted by date modified

Tags: perl, sorting, search

Directory:

```
C:/test
C:/test/A1/apples.txt    Modified 1-12-2013
C:/test/B1/oranges.txt   Modified 1-12-2014
C:/test/C1/bananas.txt   Modified 1-12-2015
```

Give the root directory (C:/test) to the perl script and it will find the directory and file most recently modified.

```
perl findfile.pl C:/test
Answer: C:/test/C1/bananas.txt
```

I need this script to work on multiple computers that I have no control over, so I cannot install "File::Find" or any other library.

I attempted the route of using the windows command dir:

```
my @txt_files = `dir C:/test /O:-D /s *.txt`;
foreach my $line (@txt_files)
{
    if($line =~ /\s+Directory of (\S+)/)
    {
        print "$1\n"; # gets the directory
    }
...
}
```

This script is not working if ran from a different drive, Z: X: etc.
Any suggestions to build off of this? Or an entirely different route will work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `opendir` and `readdir` for reading directories, use `-X` (check `perldoc -f -X`) for checking last modified date and if it is a file or directory, use regexp to find .txt files. Maintain a queue of found directories and just run a `while` loop taking elements from it until it is empty.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

unless ($ARGV[0]) { die "No starting directory specified" }
my @dir_queue = $ARGV[0];
my $most_recent_name;
my $most_recent_time;

while (@dir_queue) {
    my $current_dir = shift(@dir_queue);
    unless (opendir(my $current_dir_dh, $current_dir)) {
        die "Can't open directory $current_dir: $!"
    } else {
        while (my $entry = readdir($current_dir_dh)) {
            if ($entry eq '.' or $entry eq '..') { next }
            my $entry_full_name = "$current_dir/$entry";
            if (-d $entry_full_name) { push @dir_queue, $entry_full_name; next }
            unless ($entry =~ /\.txt$/i) { next }
            if (!$most_recent_time or ($most_recent_time > -M $entry_full_name)) {
                $most_recent_time = -M $entry_full_name;
                $most_recent_name = $entry_full_name;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (defined $most_recent_name) {
    print "Most recently modified: $most_recent_name"
} else {
    print "No files found."
}
```

Comment: Wow! Absolutely perfect! Gives me exactly what I want. Now for me to go through it and understand it all...

Comment: @GraysonHenry, ask here in comments if you need explanation of any piece.

Comment: I spent some time and now understand it. Started programming in Perl late last year so needed to look up "next" "-M" "-d" and unless, but they seemed fairly straight forward. Any suggestions on how to go about making this run faster? In a more complex Directory structure, we could have countless folders at the root layer and making the search take some time. I was trying to add in a case statement check for certain folders, but the current logic that I have makes it check for that folder, at every layer (If that doesn't make sense let me know).

Comment: @GraysonHenry, if you have any conditions for directories, check them before `push @dir_queue`.

Comment: Got everything I need, you helped save us SO much time!